# Autolaunched flow debug success but not updating records

Tags: visual-workflow, debugging

Autolaunched flow to update partner claim based on opp field and then update record name. Says success but no records updated. Both update record thingies are pasted below and showing "All records that meet the filter criteria are ready to be updated when the next screen, pause, or local action is executed or when the interview finishesenter image description here" in the debug. HALP?!?!?

[image]

[image]
enter image description here
[image]

Comment: are you debugging in rollback mode?

Comment: No. I'm not. Should I?

Comment: rollback mode doesn't actually commit any data to the database.

Comment: I combined the updates into one and it works when I debugin flow but not in real time. It is activated.

Comment: turn the debug log on and look to see what happens when the flow does the Update Records